# Not Detecting Colors Properly Java

Tags: java

I'm in grade 12 right now and I working on a Pacman game for my computer science class.

What I so far have is a file called `Play.java` that runs the actual game. I have an `init` method that initializes the sprite sheets, images, and animations. Then I have a `render` method that draws the maze and Pacman on the screen. Last, I have an `update` method that pretty much updates whats on the screen.

This is what's inside the `update` function:

```
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException {
        pacman.update(delta);

        Input input = gc.getInput();

        Color walls;

        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)) {
            walls = maze.getColor((int) pacmanPosX, (int) pacmanPosY - 2);
            if (walls.getRed() == 0 && walls.getGreen() == 0 && walls.getBlue() == 0) {
                pacman = pacmanAnimation[2];
                pacmanPosY -= delta * .1f;
            }
        } else if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)) {
            walls = maze.getColor((int) pacmanPosX, (int) pacmanPosY + 20);
            if (walls.getRed() == 0 && walls.getGreen() == 0 && walls.getBlue() == 0) {
                pacman = pacmanAnimation[3];
                pacmanPosY += delta * .1f;
            }
        } else if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)) {
            walls = maze.getColor((int) pacmanPosX - 2, (int) pacmanPosY);
            if (walls.getRed() == 0 && walls.getGreen() == 0 && walls.getBlue() == 0) {
                pacman = pacmanAnimation[0];
                pacmanPosX -= delta * .1f;
            }
        } else if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)) {
            walls = maze.getColor((int) pacmanPosX + 20, (int) pacmanPosY);
            if (walls.getRed() == 0 && walls.getGreen() == 0 && walls.getBlue() == 0) {
                pacman = pacmanAnimation[1];
                pacmanPosX += delta * .1f;
            }
        }
    }
```

So basically I allow the user to move Pacman around the screen and I check the pixel color of the future position that Pacman may land. If the future position is not black, Pacman may not continue moving in that direction. This concept works for the most part, except Pacman can move through a rectangle if it starts off at the top left/right corner.

Here's an image of what I'm talking about:

[image: screenshot]

I circled in red the areas where Pacman is able to move when it shouldn't.

How do I fix this issue? I don't want Pacman to be on top of any blue rectangles. If you want me to add more code, I can but I think the `update` method is enough for now. Just trying to create an MCVE.

Also, I'm using Slick2D and LWJGL for this game.

Comment: I strongly suggest you separate the _model_ (the maze and the locations your PacMan can occupy) from the _display_ (aka "rendering") of the screen.  This is a fundamental concept that will save you a huge amount of time in the long run.  The model contains all the quantized locations in which a PacMan (or other sprite) can exist, but these locations are numbered/identified independently of what is being drawn.  They are an abstract representation.  Then you don't have to look up colors or anything else.  The rendering code is separate from your game logic...

Comment: ... and is responsible only for updating the screen display.  All calculation of the game's state transitions occurs in the abstract model.  This is a major change in your code, but if you separate the model from the display (aka the "view") the coding will be a lot easier.  Learn this now, because it is crucial to everything you will do in the future.

Comment: Exactly as Jim Garrison mentioned. Separation of concerns is one of the most important principles in programming. If you are a young programmer, I strongly suggest you that you learn what this is and how to apply it in your programs. It will save you a from many many troubles. In particular, rendering should not affect gameplay desicions, like whether pacman can move. Rendering does only render. Model your game's logic separate from the graphics. Game logic and rendering are 2 separate concerns.

Comment: Here's a hint on how to start: First, forget the display completely.  The virtual space in which the actors exist is a rectangular grid.  Each grid point is a location the center of an actor can occupy.  These may map to pixels in one direction, either vertical or horizontal depending on whether the passage is vertical or horizontal, but _that is a design choice to make rendering easier_, not integral.  Now devise a data structure representing that model and write your game logic using that grid.  ***Then*** write the rendering code.

Comment: @JimGarrison Separating the model from the display will take up too much time. I'm on a tight schedule so I'm stuck with what I got. But, I do like your idea and I will keep that in mind in the future as I will be majoring in computer science this fall. Any other ideas of what I can do now to fix my color detection issue?

Comment: There's not enough in the code you show to help, unfortunately. We'd need to see quite a bit more.  Are you debugging by setting breakpoints and single-stepping through the relevant code to see where and why it's going off the rails?  If not, stop everything and learn how to use the IDE debugger _immediately_.  If you are not using the IDE debugger to its full capability, you MUST learn to do so if you want to make your deadline.  It's the only path open to you regardless of the time you must invest in learning it.

Comment: "Just trying to create an MCVE"  - while this one is M it is certainly not CV. For down and right you use step size of 20 : `pacmanPosX + 20` . For left and up you use 2 : `pacmanPosX - 2` . Any reason for it ? Could 20 be bigger than the blue area size ?

Comment: @c0der It works fine when I set it to those step size values. Like I said, it's the top parts of the rectangle that's giving the problem. Everywhere else is fine.

Comment: I don't think it answers my question. "it's the top parts of the rectangle that's giving the problem" - what I understand from it is that the problem occurs when moving down, right ?  `pacmanPosX + 20` why 20 ? What happens when you change it to 2 ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @c0der If I change it to 2, it doesn't detect the blue rectangles properly. Rather it detects fairly late. Would like me to post a very quick video of my problem? I think that might clear up some confusion.

Comment: See previous comment about [mcve]

Comment: @c0der Do you want me to add the `init` or `render` method to the post? I don't know what else to add. The `update` method is what I believe where the problem occurs.